# Show that a subgroup of $A_5$ that contains a 3 cycle and acts transitively on $1,2,3,4,5$ coincides with $A_5$

Tags: group-theory, permutations

I know $A_5$ is simple, so my line of logic would be to prove that a group containing a 3-cycle that acts transitively on 1,2,3,4,5 must be a normal subgroup of $A_5$. I'm just not so sure how to do this.

Also my knowledge on the group $A_5$ is pretty poor, I have trouble visualising a lot of the concepts around permutation groups so any extra explanations would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Hint :Let $H$ be such subgroup. Then $H$  is divisible by $5$ and by $3$. Hence by 15. Now, if $K$ is a subgroup of $A_{5}$ of index $m>1$, then we get a non trivial homomorphism from $A_{5}$ to $S_{m}$, and it is injective (why?)... then we get that $m>4$. 
Edited: Let $K$ be a subgroup of $A_{5}$ of index $m>1$.  Then the action of $A_{5}$ on the set of cosets of $A_{5}/K$ by left multiplication induces a non trivial homomorphism from $A_{5}$ to $S_{m}$. Since $A_{5}$ is simple, and the homomorphism is non trivial, then it is injective therefore $S_{m} \geq 60$ so $m \geq 5$.
Our subgroup $H$ has order greater or equal to 15, hence is the whole $A_{5}$

Comment: When you say H is divisible by 5 and 3, do you mean the order of H?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the bad notation!